# Why can a const member function modify a static data member?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, static, constants

In the following `C++` program, modifying a **static data member** from a `const` function is working fine:

```
class A 
{
  public:   
    static int a; // static data member

    void set() const
    {
        a = 10;
    }
};
```

But modifying a **non-static data member** from a `const` function does not work:

```
class A 
{
  public:   
    int a; // non-static data member

    void set() const
    {
        a = 10;
    }
};
```

**Why can a `const` member function modify a `static` data member?**

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us which platform and compiler you are working with? So we can determine if the behavior is a bug related to your specific setup or if the behavior is indeed correct and just needs to be explained.

Comment: @AlexZywicki G++ compiler on Linux platform.

Comment: No need. It's intentional and all C++ compilers must support it. But why are good questions like this not upvoted any more?

Comment: It's a dupe, but it's better written than the other one thanks to a better MCVE, so I used this as target.

Comment: Even worse, a member function `void clobber(A &x) const { x.a = 0; }` is allowed!

Comment: The motivation here is that `const` means a member function of an object cannot modify *that one object*. It can modify other objects of the same class, or `static` data, which is associated with the class, not any particular instance of it. (Or `mutable` data members, which were created to be the exception to this rule.)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It's the rule, that's all. And for good reason.

The `const` qualifier on a member function means that you cannot modify non-`mutable` non-`static` class member variables.

By way of offering some rationalisation, the `this` pointer in a `const` qualified member function is a `const` type, and `this` is inherently related to an *instance* of a class. `static` members are not related to a class instance. You don't need an instance to modify a `static` member: you can do it, in your case, by writing `A::a = 10;`.

So, in your first case, think of `a = 10;` as shorthand for `A::a = 10;` and in the second case, think of it as shorthand for `this->a = 10;`, which is not compilable since the type of `this` is `const A*`.

Comment: Just a slight error here: Since you can't reassign the `this` pointer, it would be of type `const A* const`  in `const`'s case.

Comment: @TaylorHansen `this` is a prvalue of pointer type. Prvalues of non-class-types are never cv-qualified.

Answer (score 22):

According to the C++ Standard (9.2.3.2 Static data members)

> 1 A static data member is **not part of the subobjects of a class**...

And (9.2.2.1 The this pointer)

> 1 In the body of a non-static (9.2.1) member function, the keyword
>   this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object
>   for which the function is called. The type of this in a member
>   function of a class X is X*. **If the member function is declared
>   const, the type of this is const X***,...

And at last (9.2.2 Non-static member functions)

> 3 ... if name lookup (3.4) resolves the name in the id-expression to a
>   non-static non-type member of some class C, and if either the
>   id-expression is potentially evaluated or C is X or a base class of X,
>   the id-expression is transformed into a class member access expression
>   (5.2.5) using **(*this)** (9.2.2.1) as the postfix-expression to the
>   left of the . operator.

Thus in this class definition

```
class A 
{
  public:   
    static int a; 

    void set() const
    {
        a = 10;
    }
};
```

the static data member `a` is not a subobject of an object of the class type and the pointer `this` is not used to access the static data member. So any member function, non-static constant or non-constant, or a static member function can change the data member because it is not a constant.

In this class definition

```
class A 
{
  public:   
    int a; 

    void set() const
    {
        a = 10;
    }
};
```

the non-static data member `a` is an subobject of an object of the class type. To access it in a member function there is used either a member access syntax of this syntax is implied. You may not use a constant pointer `this` to modify the data member. And the pointer this is indeed has type `const A *` within the function `set` because the function is declared with the qualifier `const`. If the function had no the qualifier in this case the data member could be changed.

Answer (score 13):

The thing is, that if a member function of a class `A` is `const`, then the type of `this` is `const X*`, and thereby prevents non-static data members from being altered (cf, for example, [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)):

> 9.3.2 The this pointer [class.this]
>
> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose
>   value is the address of the object for which the function is called.
>   The type of this in a member function of a class X is X*. If the
>   member function is declared const, the type of this is const X*, ...

If `a` is a non-static data member, then `a=10` is the same as `this->a = 10`, which is not allowed if the type of `this` is `const A*` and `a` has not been declared as `mutable`. Thus, since `void set() const` makes the type of `this` being `const A*`, this access is not allowed.

If `a` is a static data member, in contrast, then `a=10` does not involve `this` at all; and as long as `static int a` by itself has not been declared as `const`, statement `a=10` is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` qualifier on a **member function** means that you cannot modify `non-mutable`, `non-static` **class data members**.